# Inserting Geometry into mySQL database with variables

Tags: mysql, variables, geometry

I am trying to be able to generate geometry and insert it into a table.  I was able to successfully do this in my line that is commented out.  I however can not seem to figure out what I am doing wrong when I use variables.  I'm missing something I'm sure.  Could anyone take a look?

```
SET @minX = 1;
SET @minY = 2;
SET @maxX = 43;
SET @maxY = 86;
SET @minXminY = concat((@minX),' ',(@minY));
SET @maxXminY = concat((@maxX),' ',(@minY));
SET @maxXmaxY = concat((@maxX),' ',(@maxY));
SET @minXmaxY = concat((@minX),' ',(@maxY));
SET @g1 = concat((@minXminY),", ",(@maxXminY),", ",(@maxXmaxY),", ",(@minXmaxY),", ",(@minXminY));
SET @g = 'POLYGON((@g1))';
##SET @g = 'POLYGON((1 2,43 2,43 86,1 86,1 2))';

INSERT INTO `db`.`table`
(`name`,
`geometry`)
VALUES
('test4',
(GeomFromText(@g)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL isn't like a scripting language, where something `"hello $foo"` will detect the variable `$foo` embedded in the string and replace the variable with the variable's contents.

Given

```
SET @g = 'POLYGON((@g1))';
```

It should be

```
SET @g = CONCAT('POLYGON((', @g1, '))')
```

So that the variable can be seen/used as an actual variable, and not simply some plain-text from the DB's point of view.